# How does ManagedProcess in Cloud Haskell work?

Tags: haskell, cloud, distributed-computing

I'm following this [tutorial](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/tutorials/tutorial3.html) and looking at the test case in [source code](https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-process-platform/blob/master/tests/TestGenServer.hs).
My code use `SimplePool.hs` in the source code and created the following file: (snippet)

```
sampleTask :: (TimeInterval, String) -> Process String
sampleTask (t, s) = sleep t >> return s 

$(remotable ['sampleTask])

jobTest :: MVar (AsyncResult (Either String String)) -> Process ()
jobTest result = do
  pid <- startTestPool 1 -- start the pool of workers here only one worker
  job <- return $ ($(mkClosure 'sampleTask) (seconds 2, "foobar"))
  -- callAsync put job into pool
  p <- callAsync pid job 
  a <- wait p
  setResult result a
  where
    setResult :: MVar a -> a -> Process ()
    setResult mvar x = liftIO $ putMVar mvar x

startTestPool :: Int -> Process ProcessId
startTestPool s = spawnLocal $ do
  _ <- runPool s
  return ()

runPool :: Int -> Process (Either (InitResult (Pool String)) TerminateReason)
runPool s =
  -- setting a to String
  let s' = poolServer :: ProcessDefinition (Pool String)
  in simplePool s s'

myRemoteTable :: RemoteTable
myRemoteTable = Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.__remoteTable initRemoteTable

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Right (transport, _) <- createTransportExposeInternals
                                    "127.0.0.1" "9901" defaultTCPParameters
  localNode       <- newLocalNode transport myRemoteTable
  result          <- newEmptyMVar
  pid             <- forkProcess localNode $ jobTest result
  ans             <- takeMVar result
  putStrLn $ show pid
  putStrLn $ show ans
```

I'm getting this error once I run it:

```
AsyncFailed (DiedException "exit-from=pid://127.0.0.1:9901:0:6")
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, I assume the job did not run correctly, must be some problem with the slave process.`p <- callAsync pid job`  this line of code I think is where the task is passed on to slave process for execution.  I looked into the [library](https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-process-platform/blob/master/src/Control/Distributed/Process/Platform/ManagedProcess/Client.hs) to find the definition of `callAsync`.  The key line in `callAsyncUsing` is `sendTo sid (CallMessage msg (Pid wpid))` where the function passes the task to the poolServer.

SimplePool.hs in the `acceptTask` the line `asyncHandle <- async proc` is where I think they spawn a new process to execute the task.  So I think maybe the async process didn't finish running cause the the caller terminated prematurely? Or could it be that the process didn't spawn correctly?  Any idea on what the best way to debug this?  Also, can someone point me in the right direction to finding out how to make the poolSever span different nodes/different computers (using Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Async.AsyncChan?)?

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code slightly, and this snippet includes the imports, so it compiles. Make sure that you are using the latest [SimplePool module](https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-process-platform/blob/master/tests/SimplePool.hs), as your code is using `simplePool` which I cannot find, and your use of `runPool` is ambiguous.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Exception (SomeException)
import Control.Distributed.Process hiding (call)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Closure
import Control.Distributed.Process.Node
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform hiding (__remoteTable)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Async
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.ManagedProcess
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Test
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Time
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Timer
import Control.Distributed.Process.Serializable()

import Network.Transport
import Network.Transport.TCP

import Data.Binary
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)

import SimplePool hiding (runPool)
import qualified SimplePool (runPool)

sampleTask :: (TimeInterval, String) -> Process String
sampleTask (t, s) = sleep t >> return s

$(remotable ['sampleTask])

jobTest :: MVar (AsyncResult (Either String String)) -> Process ()
jobTest result = do
  pid <- startTestPool 1 -- start the pool of workers here only one worker
  let job = $(mkClosure 'sampleTask) (seconds 2, "foobar")
  -- callAsync put job into pool
  p <- callAsync pid job
  a <- wait p
  setResult result a
  where
    setResult :: MVar a -> a -> Process ()
    setResult mvar x = liftIO $ putMVar mvar x

startTestPool :: Int -> Process ProcessId
startTestPool s = spawnLocal $ do
  _ <- runPool s
  return ()

runPool :: Int -> Process (Either (InitResult (Pool String)) TerminateReason)
runPool = SimplePool.runPool

myRemoteTable :: RemoteTable
myRemoteTable = Main.__remoteTable initRemoteTable

main :: IO ()
main = do

  Right (transport, _) <- createTransportExposeInternals
                                "127.0.0.1" "9901" defaultTCPParameters
  localNode       <- newLocalNode transport myRemoteTable
  result          <- newEmptyMVar
  pid             <- forkProcess localNode $ jobTest result
  ans             <- takeMVar result
  print pid >> print ans
```

Running this compilable code:

```
$ ./Example 
pid://127.0.0.1:9901:0:3
AsyncDone (Right "foobar")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm getting compile error. In src/Control/Distributed/Process/Platform/ManagedProcess/Internal/Types.hs line 33, 34. `Module 'Control.Distributed.Process' does not export 'Message'` Perhaps it's suppose to be from 'Control.Distributed.Process.Internal.Types' in the distributed-process-0.4.2 package?

Comment: After trying to fix that problem, I ran into another problem.  In the `Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.ManagedProcess.Server` the function `handleMessage` is out of scope, any idea on where this function is imported from?

Comment: Ah, `handleMessage` was added to distributed-process after the (current) latest release 0.4.2, in commit https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-process/commit/23282e0093316080a559d3e7efadd41ab4b54d4d . If you want this code to work, you need to use the development branch of distributed-process: https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-process/tree/development which will be in release 0.5.0.

Comment: Rob is spot on about that - distributed-process-platform currently relies on bleeding edge changes to distributed-process. That will get sorted out properly when we release to hackage, and I'm hoping to provide a meta-package to simplify installing everything you need, which will have branches/revisions available for pulling HEAD from either the stable (master) or development branches of all the haskell-distributed projects.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the SimplePool sample module from the distributed-process-platform test suite has been promoted to a fully fledged component of the library. Its new location on the latest (development) branch is https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-process-platform/blob/development/src/Control/Distributed/Process/Platform/Task/Queue/BlockingQueue.hs.

Some names/types have changed, so you may need to update your code in order to continue using it.